# Mac sudo password incorrect when create database in postgreSQL

Tags: database, macos, postgresql, sudo

I'm trying to set up a Postgresql database for the first time.

After installing postgresql91, i opened up terminal and did the following:

```
sudo su - postgres
createdb dbname
Password: 
Sorry try again.
```

I typed in my Mac admin password, why do i get this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sudo you type in your password, not root's.

Comment: I typed in my password. Is there another password for postgresql?

Comment: No, it's not about postgres password, the message comes from `sudo`, so it's not yet gone as far as `su` and `postgres`. What it says is that you've entered wrong password for the user that started `sudo`.

Comment: ok. Could it be because i used sudo su - postgres to start up postgresql?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what exactly is it you're tying. I mean — `sudo su - postgres`, but where does the `createdb` line comes from? There's no prompt?

Comment: Can you just try `sudo -u postgres createdb`?

Comment: after i do sudo su - postgres, it changes the directory to postgres. Then i typed in createdb dbname and so on.

Comment: `createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: Permission denied
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: `sudo su - postgres` doesn't really start postgres, it starts postgres user's login shell.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4596/discussion-between-adnan-and-michael-krelin-hacker)

Comment: Yes, you have no postgres running.